# What is a good way to narrow down a list of elements by their attribute or other conditions?

Tags: python, optimization, filtering

I want to narrow down a list of elements of a list by their attribute, type or other conditions.

Something like `elements.only_type(Flower).get_nearest_to(player)` looks much nicer than `min(filter(lambda i: isinstance(i, Flower), elements), lambda i: i.pos.distance_to(player.pos)`.

Is the following a good idea in terms of efficiency, clean code and simplicity?
Or is there already a good way, implementation or design pattern for this?

```
class Selector(object):
    def __init__(self, selection):
        self.s3l3ct1on = selection

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return type(self)(getattr(el, name) for el in self.s3l3ct1on)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.s3l3ct1on)

    def filter(self, function):
        return type(self)(filter(function, self.s3l3ct1on))
```

And this is how it can be used: (`A` is just a class with two attributes: `a` and `b`)

```
>>> sel = [A(3, 4), A(0, 9), A('test', 3), A(4,22), A(3, 9)]
>>> Selector(sel)
<__main__.Selector object at 0x13b0a90>
>>> list(Selector(sel))
[<__main__.A object at 0x13b0fd0>,
 <__main__.A object at 0x13b0b50>,
 <__main__.A object at 0x13b0150>,
 <__main__.A object at 0x13b0710>,
 <__main__.A object at 0x13b06d0>]
>>> set(Selector(sel).a)
{0, 'test', 3, 4}
>>> list(Selector(sel).b)
[4, 9, 3, 22, 9]
>>> s = Selector(sel).b.filter(lambda i: i%2 == 0)
>>> list(s)
[4, 22]
```

Comment: BTW, there's no need to name the instance attribute `s3l3ct1on` instead of `selection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every kind of selection process you mention can be defined in terms of an `itertools` iterator. The following formalizes that and could easily be extended to support more even more kinds. The syntax to use it seems very readable.

Although I didn't do any performance testing, I'd expect the results to be competitive as almost all of the overhead involved is in the constructor method. The only thing likely to be a even a tiny bit faster would be to replacing its usage with the equivalent `itertools` iterator function -- so it seems like it might be a valid convenience tool to use if you expected to be doing a lot of this kind of processing.

```
import itertools

class Selector(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable, **kwargs):
        if not kwargs:
            self.iterator = iterable
        elif len(kwargs) > 1:
            raise ValueError('only one selector type keyword allowed')
        else:
            selector, target = kwargs.items()[0]

            if selector == 'by_attr':
                self.iterator = itertools.imap(lambda obj: getattr(obj, target), iterable)
            elif selector == 'by_type':
                self.iterator = itertools.ifilter(lambda obj: isinstance(obj, target), 
                                                  iterable)
            elif selector == 'by_func':
                self.iterator = itertools.ifilter(target, iterable)
            else:
                raise ValueError('unknown selector type keyword')

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.iterator


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from selector import Selector

    class A(object):
        def __init__(self, a, b):
            self.a, self.b = a, b

    class Flower(object):
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

    sel = [A(3, 4), A(0, 9), A('test', 3), A(4,22), A(3, 9)]
    print list(Selector(sel, by_attr='a'))

    sel = [42, Flower('Buttercup'), [1,2,3,5,8], A(20, 13), Flower('Rose')]
    print list(Selector(sel, by_type=Flower))

    sel = [4, 9, 3, 22, 9]
    print list(Selector(sel, by_func=lambda i: i%2 == 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the class itself a subclass of list for simplicity.

```
class Elements(list):
   def only_type(self, t):
       return Elements(i for i in self if isinstance(i, t))

   def get_nearest(self, who):
       return min(self, key=lambda x: x.pos.distance_to(who.pos))

el = Elements([Flower(), Person(), Flower(), Something()])

el.only_type(Flower).get_nearest(player)
```

Same thing with `Selector`